# How to sync changes of branch "Main" to branch "Feature01" which created from branch "Main"

Tags: git

I have `Main` branch from which I created 10 to 15 branches for each feature i.e. `Feature01`, `Feature02`, and `Feature03` ... `Feature015`.

I am working on `Feature01` branch, I did some commit also, but not yet merged to `Main` branch.

But others branches i.e. `Feature02` to `Feature15`are merged into `Main` branch.

I need to work on `Feature01` branch to add more code. but now I want to get all code from `Main` branch to my `Feature01` branch and then I want to work on `Feature01` branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the `Main` branch into the `Feature01` branch:

```
git checkout Feature01
git merge Main
```

Or you could consider rebasing `Feature01` on the `Main` branch:

```
git checkout Feature01
git rebase Main    # or maybe origin/Main
```

The rebasing option would be best suited if you are the only one working with the `Feature01` branch, and this branch has not been shared publicly yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you merged Feature02 to Feature15 into Main already, now **you need to merge the Main branch into Feature01**, to keep it up to date.

This way Feature01 will contain all the changes you made in the other branches, but Main won't have your unfinished work from the Feature01 branch.

Once you are done working on feature 1, you can merge Feature01 back to Main.

When you have a lot of people working on your repository, you regularly merge Main into your feature branch, this way it doesn't go out date.

Hope this helps.